# RelativeLayout as Fragment container android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a `RelativeLayout` which I have considered as a fragment container. But when I load another fragment, the new fragment replaces only one section of the layout and not the complete layout.

Here is my code:-

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myframe_container"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:text="Portfolio &gt;"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textPortfolio"
                android:textColor="#32B5E3"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textPortfolio"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:background="#F7F7F7"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Investment value:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/txtInvestValue"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:text="(0%)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Capital invested:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/txtCapitalValue"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>  --------->>>> Covers only upto this layout the below layout still shows
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="#F7F7F7">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Income:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="13dp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/txtIncomeValue"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main.cs

```
TVPortfolio.Click += delegate
                {
                    PortfolioFragment fragment2 = new PortfolioFragment(this);
                    FragmentTransaction fTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.myframe_container, fragment2);


                    fTx.Commit();
                };
```

Is it that I need to only use a `FrameLayout` as the fragment container?

Comment: Please post the code adding the fragment. Otherwise we can't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can't see complete Layout use **Scroll Layout** as the parent Layout.So that you can scroll the Activity to see all the components.

Comment: Its not about not seeing the layout. I have multiple linearLayouts in my main Relative layout which is the frame container. When I load the next fragment only the first linear layout is replaced and can see the rest of the linearlayouts of the previous fragment as is

Comment: So you are saying that LinearLayout 1 is replaced but remaining 3 LinearLayout are still visible in your activity ?